# Do enemies and objects respawn?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Although I've played the game for some time now, I still couldn't find out whether certain objects and NPCs respawn or not.

I'm particularly interested in:

- Enemies
- Herbs
- Lootable objects.

While playing I've often encountered some locations where I was sure that I killed some enemies that weren't there anymore after a second visit. On the other hand I've also got the feeling that some enemies respawned although I  killed them.

Now do enemies and objects actually respawn or was that just my imagination.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Enemies respawn if you don't clear an area - if it's a den/camp, and you "complete" it (dull grey on the map), they will no longer respawn
- Herbs respawn all the time
- Lootable objects (chests, crates, etc) do not respawn

Comment: Just testing to see if Herbs spawn based on in-game time or zoning, as I'm curious now (and "all the time" is an awful description).

Comment: Are you done now?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to farm monsters just save and load the game, they will be back. After doing this mediating sometimes works too.