# Do monsters around destroyed nests and the nests themselves respawn?

Tags: the-witcher-3

So there are these 3-4 nekker nests not far from each other between Reardon Manor and Benek signposts. I remember killing all the nekkers and destroying all the nests. Yesterday I was travelling through the same area and suddenly saw that there're bunch of nekkers around, dismounted Roach, killed them all and when I approached the nests they had the destroy option. Checked the map and icons for all the nests were grayed out(meaning they're already desstroyed). Do destroyed monster nests respawn?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221714/do-enemies-and-objects-respawn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, destroyed nests and monsters respawn over time.

Comment: Is this from a source or personal experience? @Wrigglenite

Comment: It's from my own experience playing the game. Most monsters in the world respawn, even when the area they're in has been "cleared". Ruins, caves, dungeons, open fields, I've seen monsters respawn in all of those.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Have you seen the ***nests*** respawn too? Your answer conflicts with [this answer to another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/221717/228394) and my own personal experience - I've never noticed a ***den*** respawn, although plenty of area-based creatures respawn (is this time based perhaps? Maybe I just never go back near cleared dens?). I'll recheck this when I get home -  travel back to white orchard on my current playthrough and see if the dens/nests there have respawned.

Comment: @Smock Yes, I have seen nests respawn, even with the dimmed icon on the map. The nest came back and I could destroy it again, and all the monsters around respawned too.

Comment: @Wrigglenite fair enough!